# Debugging an error minified js code on IE11 Metro?

Tags: javascript, debugging, internet-explorer-11

We have carefully isolated a javascript error in our app which manifests under the following conditions:

- The program is minified (with uglify2)
- IE 11
- Metro mode only (despite MS suggesting desktop and metro mode are identical!)

So yeah. Very specific.

Luckily (?) the error propagates up into requirejs, but only gives a cryptic "module has timed out" error. Without requirejs, I imagine the error would just silently bubble to the top, and we'd have no indication (other than a broken app).

So, given that IE11 doesn't have debugging tools, a console, or source mapping, are there any bright ideas about how to debug this error?

Comment: Does it act the same way in fullscreen mode with desktop IE11? At least when you use it that way you could use the F12 developer tools.

Comment: Naw, to my knowledge there's no way to access the dev tools in fullscreen IE metro mode.

Comment: What I meant was, go to the desktop, start IE11, and press F11 to enter fullscreen mode in the desktop. You can press F12 to bring up developer tools in *that* mode, but can still see a full-screen display if needed. Unfortunately it seems like the console doesn't show anything unless dev tools is open.

Comment: Ah yeah, so unfortunately the desktop mode doesn't produce the bug at all. It _has_ to be in metro mode, not just fullscreen.